# Как получить список всех встроенных функций python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, list

Есть ли способ получить список имен всех встроенных функций python?

Типа:

```py
lst = [abs, all, any, ascii ... super, tuple, type, zip]
```

Причем не строк, а ссылок на функции, чтобы их можно было вызвать без eval().

Comment: super, tuple и т.п. это не функции. import types
builtins_funcs = [f for f in vars(_ _builtins_ _).values() if isinstance(f, types.BuiltinFunctionType)]

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, а что такое `super` если не функция? Не декоратор же?

Comment: это класс <class 'super'>

Comment: @vadimvaduxa, может и есть такой класс, но, знаете ли, если следовать вашей логике, `zip` тоже класс. Мне не интересно, существуют ли классы с аналогичными именами, мне нужны _функции_.

Comment: @Глеб, это не *классы с аналогичными именами*, а *просто* классы. И, кстати, декоратор - тоже функция. )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Например, так:

```py
>>> import builtins
>>> lst = [v for k, v in vars(builtins).items() if k[0].islower()]
>>> lst[0]
<built-in function abs>
```

Пояснения:

1. `builtins` - модуль со всеми встроенными объектами (в т. ч. функциями) (см. [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html#module-builtins));
2. встроенная функция `vars` работает аналогично `dir`, но возвращает словарь вида `{'идентификатор': значение}`;
3. мы перебираем этот словарь, и отбираем только те атрибуты модуля `builtins`, которые начинаются с маленькой буквы.

Возможно, что этот способ не очень красив, но работает.

Comment: Нет, почему же, очень даже красиво. Разве что вместо islower() можно использовать ascii_lowercase из модуля string. Так длиннее, правда.

Comment: Попробуйте `if callable(v)`

Comment: А, хотя там полно лишнего так будет не вариант

Comment: 1. `import inspect` - лишний, в коде не используется, 2. выводятся также классы типа map,str и так далее

Comment: Предложил бы попробовать `if (t := str(v)).startswith('<built-in function') and t.count('_') == 0`

Comment: @АлексейР, в вопросе указан пример такого списка, и в нём есть `tuple` - значит классы можно. Насчёт `inspect` - поправил.